# Android performance issues with SDK 5.4.0 GA?

Tags: appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

I have just compiled an existing app with the latest SDK 5.4.0 GA and was surprised to see some weird issues that look like performance issues but I am not sure.

I use an activity indicator (Ti.UI.createActivityIndicator) while time consuming things like loading data in memory or fetching data from the app server take place, and with the new SDK the animation is really choppy. The same app under the exact same conditions but compiled with 5.3.1 GA shows the activity indicator nice and smooth so it is something related to the 5.4.0 GA.

Any idea what it might be and if this is a bug or something I might need to change in terms of configuration?

I have tried switching the run-on-main-thread property but it had no impact.

The overall performance of the app does not appear to be impacted - hard to tell really.

No such issues with iOS.

Any suggestions?

Comment: i am having issues with iOS and database issues with the newest update, for some reason `db.execute("COMMIT");` works with android but not iOS. Starting to lose faith in appcelerator.